# Slickgrid Example-6 (Remote Data) and Example-9 (Re-order)

Tags: jquery, asp-classic, slickgrid

I am trying to combine Example-6 (Remote Data) and  Example-9 (Re-order).
I have wrote below code but I get "TypeError: data.slice is not a function". Could you please help me to overcome to this? My code is as below.

example6-ajax-loading  html
example9-row-reordering html

```
var loader = new Slick.Data.RemoteModel(); /* REMOTE DATA USE */
data=data.loader; /* DRAG & DROP USE */
```

the complete code. JsFiddle

[JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/C9L8a/)

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Slick.Data.RemoteModel` exposes `data` as an object with a `length` property and row indices as keys, which is similar to an array but does not have methods from `Array.prototype` like `slice`.

See: https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/master/slick.remotemodel.js#L10

- One option would be to copy `loader.data` as an array before using methods such as `slice`. Because it has a length property and keys as numbers, this is possible with `Array.prototype.slice.call()`

  ```
  moveRowsPlugin.onMoveRows.subscribe(function (e, args) {
      var extractedRows = [],
          left,
          right;
      var rows = args.rows;
      var insertBefore = args.insertBefore;
      var dataAsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(loader.data);
      left = dataAsArray.slice(0, insertBefore);
      right = dataAsArray.slice(insertBefore, dataAsArray.length);
      // ...
  });
  ```
- Another option would be to extend `Slick.Data.RemoteModel` to provide utility methods for moving a row to an index.